# How to add multiple web applications in one web role?

Tags: asp.net, azure, cloud, azure-web-roles

I want to add two applications inside one web role in Windows Azure. I'm using Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways of doing this.

The azure web role accelerator supports having multiple sites in a single web role (see https://github.com/microsoft-dpe/wa-accelerator-webroles). The documentation online regarding this is a little out of date due to the project having been discontinued. However its simple to setup. Just download the stuff from Github, compile and deploy the project from the download to your azure web-role, this then gives you an admin site where you can setup multiple applications within the web-role. You then deploy your application to there using web-deploy.

You can also add multiple sites to the service definition file, see http://www.wadewegner.com/2011/02/running-multiple-websites-in-a-windows-azure-web-role/ for an example of doing this.

Comment: Thanks for the urls Neil that helped.
Now what I'm worried about is how web publish will help in fail over and recovery scenario. Correct me if I'm wrong; on Windows Azure web publishes are not restored in case of fail over only package deployment is restored.

Comment: No problems. With the web role accelerator you're still safe regarding a recovery. The accelerator uses blob storage to store you're deployments. It then periodically checks each VM under the web role for instances of deployed applications and deploys them if they're not there.

Comment: Ok that's fantastic. Thanks for the answers Neil, appreciate it very much.